# How to disable a passwordless account

Tags: login, user-management

I have set my nephew's account to login without a password, but sometimes I want to prevent that account from logging in.

This is the process I followed:

- Set the account to login with no password, save the changes
- Set the account to disabled, save the changes

After rebooting the login screen still allows his account to login without a password.

In other words, I've set the account to disabled, but it's still it's possible to login from that account without a password. Is this a bug? How can I disable an account which has no password? Is there a workaround I can use?

[image]

Comment: How is he able to log in?

Comment: It was a passwordless account before I disabled it. I just need to click in his user and login, it must be related to the account having no password to begin with.

Comment: Yes several times, the funny thing is I disabled the account several days ago, and today by mistake clicked in his user and to my surprise the account logged in!

Comment: Just to be sure, he don't needed to type a password before (neither now as I just found out) to login.

Comment: @chaskes Please see my edit, maybe a bug. I could make a video if it's necessary...

Comment: @chaskes Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 32bits

Comment: Thanks for the additional edits. I simplified the question down to the essential point and restated it as a request for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can use usermod command to his account, just type on terminal:

```
# usermod -L <username>
```

Or take a look for more command by opening help.

```
# usermod --help
```

Answer (score 2):

I have to use this:

```
sudo usermod --expiredate 1 ruben
```

Because that account had NO password

From man usermod

```
-L, --lock
           Lock a user's password. This puts a '!' in front of the encrypted
           password, effectively disabling the password. You can't use this
           option with -p or -U.

           Note: if you wish to lock the account (not only access with a
           password), you should also set the EXPIRE_DATE to 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `accountsservice` that has been confirmed in 12.04, but a quick test shows it still applies to 13.10 and 14.04

[Disabling then Re-Enabling login without password does remove user from nopasswdlogin group](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/1169054)

The workaround given there is to manually remove the user from the `nopasswdlogin` group:

```
sudo gpasswd -d username nopasswdlogin
```

This solution is a little cleaner than `usermod` or editing `lightdm.conf` since it gets straight to the real issue.

This is not related to using automatic login. The bug occurs only when you change the user from `Login without password` to `Disable this account`.

You can avoid the bug entirely by first using the User Settings dialog to a add a password *before* disabling the account in User Settings.

I added a note to the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

After running this you can disable LighDM Login for ruben not tty login,

`echo 'allow-ruben=false' >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf && echo 'allow-guest=false' >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
   This will hide login option for ruben.
```

To show a **manual login option** you can run this [generally for root login],

`echo 'greeter-show-manual-login=true' >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
   after this you can log in to ruben by typing ruben into Login option and pressing enter two times
```